# How can I execute a function when a user hits the back button or swipes to close a screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to always execute a function when a screen is closed, either when a user presses the back button or does a swipe to close the page.

What I have tried is to use `WillPopScope`

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: CupertinoScaffold( ... the rest of my tree
```

```
  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    myFunction();
    return true;
  }
```

While this does successfully execute my function whenever the page is closed via the back button, it seems to have disabled being able to swipe to go back on iOS.  Swipe to go back on android still seems to function.

Is there another way of doing this so I can retain the swipe to go back functionality on iOS?

##### edit:

Just incase it matters, `myFunction()` involves a provider and context and throws an error when I try to call it from `dispose`.
In actuality myFunction() is:

```
context.read(myVisibilityProvider).changeVisibility(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

I successfully managed to run a function calling it from `dispose` retaining the iOS swipe to back gesture.

```dart
class ScrondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScrondScreenState createState() => _ScrondScreenState();
}

class _ScrondScreenState extends State<ScrondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }

  void myFunction() {
    print('I run');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myFunction();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

console:
`flutter: I run`

Comment: I originally tried that but kept getting this error `The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.`.  It might have to do with what my function does which involves using context:  `context.read(myVisibilityProvider).changeVisibility(false);`

Comment: Yeah, that's true context can't be accessed from `dispose` even `mounted` check won't work.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I just found this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203.  looks like I'm not the only one with this problem